# Chromatic numbers of geometric duals to a fixed graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, topological-graph-theory

A planar graph $G$ has some set of embeddings $\{E_\gamma:G \hookrightarrow R^2\}$.
Each of these embeddings has associated with it a geometric dual graph $G^*_\gamma$.
Using $\chi$ to denote chromatic number:

**Question 1:** For a given graph $G$, what is known about the set of integers
$\{\chi(G^*_\gamma)\}$? Is it, for instance, guaranteed to be an
interval?

A similar question can be asked about cellular embeddings of $G$ on higher-genus surfaces:

**Question 2:** For a given $G$, what is known about the chromatic numbers of the
surface duals of cellular embeddings of $G$? What about those
embeddings which share the same genus?

Comment: I've been unable to find much work related to this question, though I suspect it's due to poor choice of query terms. I also originally posted this question to [math.stackexchange/...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3769491/chromatic-number-range-of-dual-graphs) but am guessing Mathoverflow is more appropriate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Question 1: you can very explicitly express the chromatic number of a dual graph, namely as the *flow number* of the primal graph (see for example: [Wikipedia: Nowhere-zero flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere-zero_flow)).

Maybe a brief comment on the variety of the set of embeddings for a given planar graph: If $G$ is a $3$-connected planar graph, then it has a unique embedding into the plane. This result is due to Whitney and it is discussed in standard textbooks for graph theory, e.g. the book of Bondy and Murty or the one by Diestel.